# What are the disandvantages for using a rule to define an \hspace-like command?

Tags: spacing, expl3, latex3

In the LaTeX2e source code `\hspace` and its star version are defined with `\hskip`s. I have defined an alternative version using rules. I cannot see any obvious disantvantages of this approach other than end of line effects. This does not worry me, as the macro is intended for instructional purposes and to be used primarily at the beginning of paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,lipsum,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_new:N \zspace_debug_dim
\dim_set:Nn\zspace_debug_dim { 1pt }

\cs_new:Npn\zspace_no_star:n #1 
    {
        \tex_vrule:D 
        width \__dim_eval:w#1\__dim_eval_end:  
        height\zspace_debug_dim 
        depth0pt
        \scan_stop:
        \nobreak
        \skip_horizontal:n {0pt}
     }

\cs_new:Npn\zspace_star:n #1
    {
          \tex_vrule:D width 
          \__dim_eval:w#1\__dim_eval_end:  
          height 0pt
          depth0pt
          \scan_stop:
          \nobreak
          \skip_horizontal:n {0pt}
   }

 \DeclareDocumentCommand {\zspace} { s m }
  {
     \IfBooleanTF {#1}
     {
       \zspace_star:n {#2}
     }
     {
       \zspace_no_star:n {#2}
     }  

  }    
\ExplSyntaxOff

\everypar{{\color{red}\vrule height1pt width12pt\relax}}

\zspace{120pt}Test \zspace*{300pt+\parindent}\lipsum[2]
\zspace{120pt}Test \zspace*{40pt+\parindent}\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Are there any other limitations of the approach and do I really need the

```
 \nobreak\skip_horizontal:n {0pt}
```

if I am using a rule? Any comments on the LaTeX3 approach are also welcome.

Comment: `:D` is for "do not use" so this can't be good style:-0 I'l need to look up what the approved interface is...

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of LaTeX3/expl3 questions :) Unless the question is purely about LaTeX3 concepts, I think [tag:expl3] is more appropriate ([possibly in addition](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3615/17423) to [tag:latex3]).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle there is a :w in xbox somewhere but didn't want to load another package. D is for Do!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle [It doesn't look like there is one.](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22tex_vrule%3AD%22&type=Code)

Comment: @SeanAllred True. I should have tagged it as such

Comment: @SeanAllred yes I was just looking, strange:-)

Comment: `height \dim_eval:n {#1}` is better than using `\__dim_eval:w`

Answer (score 3):

The major features of skips are that they can stretch, and are discarded at a linebreak, and can be removed with `\unskip`. A rule doesn't have any of these features, so in general they are less flexible although if you don't need those features then you could use a rule, but why not a skip or kern?

The documented reason for the extra `hskip\z@skip` in `\hspace` is to guard against `\unskip` but as rules are not removable this does not apply here.

Comment: Main reason for the rule one can change its height and view it during a debug session. It is also use for vspace, so I thought why not for horizontal mode, with the exception as you stated.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides It's not normally used for vspace, which is a `vskip` mostly.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides If you want something that acts like glue but can be easily made visible `\leaders` are closer to what you need than rules.

Comment: Dave you probably right leaders are better. `\tex_leaders:D` ok?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides `./trunk/l3trial/xbox/xbox.dtx:% Somewhere is needed for rules, kerns, leaders: where to put these?`  seems `:D` is the state of the art currently:-)